# SQL Server stored procedure doesn't return data, although data exists

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getAllSectionPartsForPage]
    (@Page nvarchar(20))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        ID, (Section + ' ID:' + CAST(ID As nvarchar(10))) AS Section 
    FROM 
        PagePartText 
    WHERE 
        [Page] = @Page
END
```

For some reason when I'm submitting the parameter with this value: '/programs/brainology-for-home.aspx' I'm not able to get any results.

Executing the same query directly in SSMS:

```
SELECT 
    ID, (Section + ' ID:' + CAST(ID As nvarchar(10))) AS Section 
FROM 
    PagePartText 
WHERE 
    [Page] = '/programs/brainology-for-home.aspx'
```

Returns the data I need

Why am I not able to get the data using stored procedure? Using other parameter in the stored procedure gets me (different) set of data but I'm not sure why I can't get the data I need using this specific parameter although it exists in the database table.

Comment: A 34 character string doesn't fit into 20 chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input parameter `@Page nvarchar(20)` to your stored procedure doesn't fully accommodate `'/programs/brainology-for-home.aspx'`

Watch...

```
DECLARE @Page nvarchar(20)
SET @Page = '/programs/brainology-for-home.aspx'
PRINT '@Page = ''' + @Page + ''''
```

Result:

`@Page = '/programs/brainology'`

Your input value is being truncated to fit the defined input parameter size.  Try expanding `@Page` to be at least `nvarchar(34)` to make this specific case work, or just blow it out to `nvarchar(max)` and never need to think about it again.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getAllSectionPartsForPage](@Page nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ID, (Section + ' ID:' + CAST(ID As nvarchar(10))) AS Section FROM PagePartText WHERE [Page] = @Page
END
```